# How do I loop through and toggle elements with the same class / VanillaJS?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, frontend

I'm doing front-end for a search engine and I have a div that will repeat many times depending on the search results. All of them need to have truncated text and show more/less buttons. I'm using the toggle class to truncate the text. I wrote the code below, however, it only works for the first div and I don't know how to make it work for all of them. Can someone please help/explain it to me?

I have tried using a `for` loop, but I think I am doing something wrong

HTML

```html
<p class="result-box-description truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit...</p>
<span class="show">show more</span>
<p class="result-box-description truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit...</p>
<span class="show">show more</span>
<p class="result-box-description truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit...</p>
<span class="show">show more</span>
```

CSS

```css
p.result-box-description {
  @include tipography(14);
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-align: justify;

}
.truncate {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

JavaScript

```js
window.onload = function () {
  document.querySelector('.show').addEventListener('click', textToggle);
};

function textToggle() {
  const paragraphs = document.getElementsByClassName('result-box-description');
  const btn = document.querySelector('.show');

  for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
    paragraphs[i].classList.toggle('truncate');
  }

  if (paragraphs.classList.contains('truncate')) {
    btn.innerHTML = 'show more';
  } else {
    btn.innerHTML = 'show less';
  }
}
```

I just want all of the divs to work the same way since I don't know what the actual number will be.

Comment: See the very 1st paragraph in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector.

Comment: You can use `querySelectorAll` and `forEach` (but `forEach` only works on Arrays, so you'd want to use `Array.from` as well.) So, something like: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.show')).forEach( element => { element.addEventListener('click', textToggle); });`

Comment: BTW, although it may be easier to add multiple listeners, it can be much faster to add just one(`document.addEventListener('click', textToggle)`), using an `if` block to make sure the clicked element is relevant, like: `function textToggle(event){ if(event.target.classList.contains('.somethingWorthClicking')){ do(stuff); } }`

Comment: @Cat yes, I used something like that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the following the correct outcome?

edit: Added toggling logic

```js
window.onload = function() {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('show')).forEach(element => element.addEventListener('click', textToggle));
};

function textToggle(ev) {
  const paragraphs = document.getElementsByClassName('result-box-description');
  const btns = document.getElementsByClassName('show');

  var btn = ev.target;
  var para = ev.target.previousSibling.previousElementSibling;
  if (para.classList.contains("truncate")) {
    for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
      paragraphs[i].classList.add('truncate');
      btns[i].innerHTML = 'show more';
    }
    btn.innerHTML = "show less";
    para.classList.remove("truncate");
  } else {
    btn.innerHTML = "show more";
    para.classList.add("truncate");
  }
}
```

```css
p.result-box-description {
  @include tipography(14);
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-align: justify;
}

.truncate {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<p class="result-box-description truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
  aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris
  nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit...</p>
<span class="show">show more</span>
<p class="result-box-description truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
  aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris
  nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit...</p>
<span class="show">show more</span>
<p class="result-box-description truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
  aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris
  nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptatelaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit...</p>
<span class="show">show more</span>
```

Comment: @vogel22 please check out the edited code, I've added the toggling that you might need

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for. I did figure it out in the end, did it very similar to what you did here :)

Answer (score 1):

You should get all "show" buttons and attach the event to each of them. You can do it like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  let shows = document.querySelectorAll('.show');
  shows.forEach((link) => { link.addEventListener('click', textToggle); });
};

function textToggle() {
  let paragraph = this.previousElementSibling;
  if (paragraph.classList.contains('truncate')) {
    paragraph.classList.remove('truncate');
    this.innerHTML = 'show less';
  } else {
    paragraph.classList.add('truncate');
    this.innerHTML = 'show more';
  }
}
```

I've used previousElementSibling inside textToggle to point to paragraph you want to toggle.

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/kinospro/pen/zVPZaJ

Comment: Thanks for the solution and your time, however, it did not work for me

Comment: I've added a link to codepen with working example. It might seem not working if there is no content overflow.

Comment: Also, there might be troubles with other browsers, than webkit-based because of the way .truncate class is written.